# Sort Array в C#

Tags: c#

Написал такой код, а он не хочет работать.
Подскажите в чем проблема? Ругается на `Array.Sort`:

```
using System;

 class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] array1 = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
            int[] arr = Array.Sort(array1);
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++){
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.sort.aspx

Comment: почитай про интерфейс IComparable 

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1 - Array.Sort:

```
Array.Sort(array1);
```

Вариант 2 - Enumerable.OrderBy:

```
array1.OrderBy(a => a).ToArray();
```